# Does the version of visual studio affects the performance of the compiled application?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, compilation

Does the version of visual studio affects the performance of the compiled application? 
For example, If i had an app that was compiled using visual studio 2010, and now i compile it with visual studio 2015, will it run faster? 
also, does the target .net framwork affects the performance of the applicatoin? 
For example, if I chose 2.0 as the target .net farmework at the project creation, and compiled it using visual studio 2015, will it have the same perfomance as an application with 4.0 as the target .net framework which was compiled with visual studio 2015?
 Does the version of visual studio affects the performance? 
does the version of the .net framework affects the performance?

Comment: It doesn't affect the performance directly, but it does affect the user in that they will be required to install a certain library by Microsoft depending on which framework you used. And the higher the version number of the framework, the more features and fixes it tends to have. Of course, this is just my personal opinion. The version of visual studio itself shouldn't affect the performance, but the version of .net framework would most likely.

Comment: @Kaitlyn i heard that they rebuilt the compiler at visual studio 2015, shouldnt that affect the performance? i mean, diffrent compiler diffrent compile results, isnt it like that?

Comment: It will only be proven once a benchmark between the two has been done. For me, as an example, I didn't really notice any difference between using either Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013, nor in the executables they compiled. But the main difference is that they each have a different "max" support of the .NET Framework, with 2010 being up till .NET Framework 4, and 2013 being up till 4.5. It may be different with Visual Studio 2015, but only someone who has used both 2010 and 2015 can truly answer your question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, so I can only make assumptions.

If the implementation of functions of the framework hasn't changed in different framework versions, then the result (operation and performance) should be identical.
But I am quite sure that MS also reworked some code, so the result very likely will be different.

If the parts of the compiler, that are used to compile your code, haven't changed in different Visual Studio versions, then the result (operation and performance) should be identical as well.
What I can tell for sure though, is, that the compiler has changed from VS 2008 to 2013 to 2015. VS 2008 was able to compile a certain program of me, 2013 failed, 2015 worked again (and I doubt that they reverted the 2015 compiler back to 2008 state, so we got AT LEAST 3 different versions).